# Set language of NSIS Installer

Tags: angular, electron, nsis

I have an angular/electron app with NSIS Installer. How Can I set language in which this installer window appears? For example I want installation directory window to be in german instead of english. I could not find any documentation about this topic.

Comment: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Creating_language_files_and_integrating_with_MUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Electron Builder documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) you should set `installerLanguages` to "de_DE" in the `nsis` key in your configuration.

If you want to use a fully custom NSIS script instead, it would just be:

```
!include MUI2.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE German

Section
...
SectionEnd
```